# Angular Binding errror - Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'input' even though the property exists

Tags: c#, angular

I created a component class as below and i am trying to bind the class fields to template but i am seeing below error

> ERROR in src/app/admin/projects/projects.component.html:41:34 - error
> NG8002: Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of
> 'input'. name="ProjectID" [(ngModel)]="newProject.projectID">

> Error occurs in the template of component ProjectsComponent.
> src/app/admin/projects/projects.component.html:49:36 - error NG8002:
> Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'input'.
> name="ProjectName" [(ngModel)]="newProject.projectName">
> src/app/admin/projects/projects.component.ts:7:16   templateUrl:
> './projects.component.html',

```
  export class ProjectsComponent implements OnInit {

  projects : Project[];
  newProject : Project = new Project();
  constructor(private projectSevice : ProjectsService) {

   }
```

I am trying to bind the Project properties to the template as below.

```
 <div class="form-group row">
            <label for="txtNewProjectID" class="col-sm-4 col-form-label">Project ID</label>
            <div class="col-sm-8">
              <input type="text" id="txtNewProjectID" style="width:100px" class="form-control" placeholder="Project ID"
                name="ProjectID" [(ngModel)]="newProject.projectID">
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group row">
            <label for="txtNewProjectName" class="col-sm-4 col-form-label">Project Name</label>
            <div class="col-sm-8">
              <input type="text" id="txtNewProjectName" class="form-control" placeholder="Project Name"
                name="ProjectName" [(ngModel)]="newProject.projectName">
            </div>
          </div>
```

Below is the Project class

```
export class Project {

    projectID: number;
    projectName: string;
    dateOfStart: string;
    teamSize: number;

    constructor(){
        this.projectID = 0;
        this.projectName = null;
        this.dateOfStart = null;
        this.teamSize = 0;
    }
}
```

I am not able to figure out what mistake i did

Comment: Hi user3198688, have you imported forms module in your module.ts file?

Comment: @Ritu Thank you, i missed importing it.

Comment: Why is this tagged c#? I was going to suggest an edit but apparently the queue is full.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use ngModel directive and general data binding with Angular, you will need to first import Angular's **FormsModule** in your module.

To do this, know what module your component is contained. And then add FormsModule in the list of imports.

For example, you can import this to the app.module.ts:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    NgbModule,
    FormsModule // Insert here
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Make sure you add this at the top of your module file:

```
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
```

Comment: yeah this was the issue, i have imported the package but i missed specifying it in the Imports array, Thanks a lot.